# Python with selenium: invalid(?) warning

Tags: python, selenium

Using python with selenium, fragment of the code:

```
  alert = driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

By run the code, i get:

```
  Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python34\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 517
  warnings.warn("use driver.switch_to.alert instead", DeprecationWarning)
  DeprecationWarning: use driver.switch_to.alert instead
```

I dont understand this, Didn't i just use driver.switch_to.alert?

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at the name of the call - once it's written with an underline, once with a dot inbetween. You are using the method `switch_to_alert()` of your `driver` object - it seems like Selenium has deprecated this method in favor of a seperated `switch_to` subclass / property.

So you should use the method `alert()` of `switch_to` of `driver`,
but you are using `switch_to_alert()` of `driver`.